# Different between get image from .jpg and .php?type=3&item_id=013c23

Tags: php, image

I wonder the pro / cons for below method to get a image:

http://image.anobii.com/anobi/image_book.php?type=3&item_id=013c23a6dd4c6115e4&time=1282904048

http://static.anobii.com/anobii/static/image/welcome/icon_welcome.png

One use php to get image and the second one just enter the url.

e.g. which one is fast?

Comment: One uses PHP's `GET` method and finds the file. Other just requests for the file. Which one do you think is fast?

Comment: haha, of course the .jpg~:D, after i post this question in here, and find out the question is very similar to save image in file system and in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They potentially serve very different purposes. If you are able to link directly to the `.png` resource, it is likely (but not guaranteed to be) a real file which is world accessible on the web.  When using a PHP script to serve the image content, a lot of different things may be happening behind the scenes.

For example, PHP is able to check the user's session or authentication credentials to provide authorization for the image.  The image binary data could be stored in a database instead of in the filesystem, or if in the filesystem, the image file could be stored *outside* the web server's document root, preventing direct access to it. One common usage is to to deny access to the file when a user is not authorized, and instead serve other image data in its place, like an "access denied" default image.

Another potential use of the PHP script could be per-session hit counting on the resource, or rate limiting clients from hitting a resource too many times.

When serving a static file, authorization, logging, etc. are limited to the capabilities of the web server as it is configured.

The question to ask isn't really which is faster, but which suits the application's business need.

Comment: thank for your answer, the key is depend on business need, e.g. if we need authentication then use php, otherwise, just .jpg